# database schema for like entities that can be combined pairwise (ActiveRecord)

Tags: activerecord, sinatra-activerecord

I am designing a database of woodwind instrument sounds, and would like to create a table that joins pairs of sounds that a performer can combine into, for example, a trill. Such relations are transitive: if sound A has a 'Sound Relation' with sound B, then sound B has that same 'Sound Relation' with sound A.

I am familiar with join tables, but I've never seen them used to join 'like' objects, only to join 'unlike' objects, such as tags and posts, so I'm wary of going that direction.

I realize the example below looks extremely dubious, but it gives an idea of what I'm after. What is a better way of doing it? (Using ActiveRecord syntax)

**Models**

```
class Sound < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :linked_sounds, through: :sound_relations, class_name: "Sound", foreign_key: ???
end

class Sound_Relation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sounds
end
```

**Migration**

```
class CreateSoundRelations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :sound_relations do |t|
      t.integer first_sound_id  # This cannot possibly be right.
      t.integer second_sound_id # Surely the transitivity of the 
                                # relationship should be more evident?
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try something like:

```
class Set  < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sound_sets
  has_many :sounds, :through => :sound_sets
end

class SoundSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sound
  belongs_to :set
end

class Sound < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sound_sets
  has_many :sets          , :through => :sound_sets
  has_many :set_sound_sets, :through => :sets          , :source => :sound_sets
  has_many :set_sounds    , :through => :set_sound_sets, :source => :sound
end
```

So, no more "sound_1" and "sound_2" ... they are both just sounds. For every sound you can also use the set_sounds method to retrieve all of the sounds associated with it.

This would also allow more than two sounds in a relation, and you might like to put a "type" on the sets model.

Edit: If you look at the query generated, you'll find that sound_sets is mentioned in there twice, once with a different alias. The key to eliminating "self" joins is to include a clause in the association along the lines of:

```
has_many :set_sounds    ,
         {where("sound_sets.sound_id != set_sound_sets_sound_set_sounds.sound_id")},
         :through => :set_sound_sets,
         :source => :sound
```

... where "sound_set_sounds" is the table alias. If you can post the query in the comments I can update this with the actual alias.

Comment: I will give this a try. Looks promising! It seems like such a commonplace problem, is there a word for this pattern, or is it functionally equivalent to a join table? Any special pitfalls to watch out for?

Comment: I'm not aware of a particular name, but in principle you're defining a new object as a set of other objects, and then just allowing multiple objects to be associated with the set. It ought to be straightforward. You might like to consider whether SoundSet needs to have other attributes so you add characteristics to the relationship.

Comment: I implemented this last night and it looks like it's going to work out swell. Since posting, however, I've also run across the notion of a 'self-join' http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins
Do you think that's a viable alternative? Or does it assume non-reciprocal relationships?

Comment: It assumes a one:many relationship, which is really more suitable for representing a hierarchy such as manager/employee, or parent/child, or assembly/component.

Comment: When I implemented this, I also included the association
'has_many: :linked_sounds, through: :groupings, source: :sounds'
(The equivalent of the last line from your example). But now, each sound is found to be linked to ITSELF once for each group with which it is associated. In other words, Sound.all[0].linked_sounds returns [1,21,1,23,1,56]. Any way to avoid that?